# How to do code coverage for HttpClientErrorException and HttpServerErrorException blocks

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to cover below HttpClientErrorException,HttpServerErrorException blocks but with below code its not getting to cover. Can some one help me please to resolve my issue.

### Class

```
public void refreshCall(RefreshCartRequest request, List<ResolvableErrorEnum> errors) {
        String url = Utils.formatHttpUrl(url, REFRESH_URL);
        try {
            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request);
            JsonNode jsonNode = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, JsonNode.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            errors.add(ErrorMessages.SM_ERR_05);
            return;
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            errors.add(ErrorMessages.SM_ERR_03);
            return;
        }
    }
```

### Test Class

```
@Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void test_refreshCall_ServerException() {
        RefreshCartRequest req = new RefreshCartRequest();
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(req);    
when(restTemplate.postForObject(URL,entity,JsonNode.class)).thenThrow(HttpServerErrorException.class);
        client.refreshCall(req,new ArrayList<ResolvableErrorEnum>());
    }
```

Comment: The entity you pass in in the method under test isn’t the same as the one you setup the thenThrow for (you call `new` in the method). Change to use `Matchers.eq` and `Matchers.any` as appropriate in the `when` setup otherwise the call won’t match.

Comment: @BeUndead can you please suggest with code

Comment: I don’t have an IDE handy so I can’t easily check. But something like `doThrow(new HttpClientErrorException()).when(restTemplate).postForObject(Matchers.any(URL.class), Matchers.any(HttpEntity.class), Matchers.any(Class.class));`

Comment: The issue being the way you’ve set it up, it will only throw if those EXACT arguments are provided, but in the method it’s a different instance of HttpEntity that comes in.